# SQL not equal query not returning rows as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a database that looks as follows (`parent_id` is a `fk` to the same table):

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | parent_id | enabled |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | null      |       1 |
|  2 | 1         |       1 |
|  3 | null      |       1 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = 1
```

returns rows successfully as I would expect, however

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id != 1
```

returns nothing.

Comment: You should [read this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-null-values.htm) and then you'll have a better understanding on handling nulls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct query about NULL value is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM category
WHERE parent_id IS NULL OR parent_id != 1
```

If you try to check is a NULL field is != by a value, it return always false (unknown for precision)

Comment: For goodness sake, I totally forgot you cannot use equality on null.  I knew it was something daft I had overlooked. #facepalm

Comment: @Unflux: It happens ;) Have a nice day